# connect to external IP fails

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp, winsock

I have been stuck with this problem for ages...

So I coded a game with multiplayer using the BSD sockets/Winsock 2 TCP. My server is up and working, I can connect to it locally (indirectly by filling in my own external ip). Everything seems to be fine. I tested with canyouseeme.org whether my ip and server port were properly port forwarded, and it was perfectly working. Then I sent my client to a friend to test it out by connecting to the server, and it failed all the time. I expected him to have connected, but I could not see anything on the server side (while canyouseenme.org even popped up as invalid client). I do not get it, do I have to do something special for external connecting in TCP?

Here is my connect function:

```
int CConnectSocket(CSocket s, unsigned short port, char* ipaddress)
{
    SOCKADDR_IN target;
    target.sin_family = AF_INET;
    target.sin_port = htons(port);
    target.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(inet_addr(ipaddress));
    if (connect(s, (SOCKADDR*)&target, sizeof(target)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        if (WSAGetLastError() == WSAEISCONN)
            return CTCP_DONE;
        else if (WSAGetLastError() != WSAEWOULDBLOCK && WSAGetLastError() != WSAEALREADY)
        {
            strcpy(inerr, "CConnectSocket: Failed to connect the socket. Error ");
            char f[6];
            sprintf(f, "%d", WSAGetLastError());
            strcat(inerr, f);
            return CTCP_ERROR;
        }
        return CTCP_WAIT;
    }
    return CTCP_DONE;
}
```

I keep looping this function until CTCP_DONE is returned (meaning I connected). My friend reported he timed out (so it returned CTCP_WAIT for too long). Again, I'm sure the client is the fault because my server was able to accept an external connection from canyouseeme.org. The IP address and port I fill in work because I can connect locally. If I change the port, local connection doesn't work anymore (proof that it is a correct argument). Changing the IP does yield the same result.

I appreciate any help! Hopefully I can solve this problem and begin the multiplayer.

EDIT

```
void CEngine::CSetSockAddr(CSockAddr* address, unsigned short port, char* ipaddress)
{
    memset(address, 0, sizeof(CSockAddr));
    address->sin_family = AF_INET;
    address->sin_port = htons(port);
    address->sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(inet_addr(ipaddress));
}
```

This is my socket address function. When I remove the htonl function, it works at my friend's side, but no at my side any more (I also host the server). My friend BTW uses XP, but since I called to use 2.2 WinSock that should be no issue. At least I hope that the setup function for WinSock guarantees a 2.2 implementation if it returns true.

EDIT 2

Hello guys,

I have got everything up and working now. It seems that if I add htonl I can connect as the host with the external IP rather than connecting with the loopback 127.0.0.0.1 or sth like that. So now I would like to know, how do I detect whether I am connecting to a server that I host? That would be a nice trick. Happy new year all!

Comment: Maybe your friend has firewall which is blocking connection.

Comment: No probably not he checked, and the same happened with another friend and people... So I have no clue.

Comment: I'm not sure, but isn't the `inet_addr()` already returning in network byte order? If so, drop the `htonl()` after that. That said, there is a `FormatString()` function which you can use to turn errorcodes into text (which you should then use to raise an exception). BTW, did you try connecting with a different tool, like e.g. a browser? It doesn't matter if the remote speaks HTTP, only to test the connection. Lastly, the error could also be in CSocket, whatever that is...

Comment: CSocket is a typedef for SOCKET variable type

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the "C"-prefix stand for?

Comment: I use it consistently in all functions I write, as a kind of feel ;)

Answer (score 1):

Is very difficult to help you without a console... but you can talk with your friend and try this:

- From your friend's PC, make a ping against your server.
- If you recieve an answer, use tracert or traceroute to find out what's the problem
- What's the route model of your friend? probably it has a System Event Log where you can check for rejected connections.

Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `htonl()` call when calling `inet_addr()`.  `connect()` expects the IP to be in network byte order, and `inet_addr()` returns the IP in network byte order, so there is no need to swap the bytes, on any platform.

Try this:

```
int CConnectSocket(CSocket s, unsigned short port, char* ipaddress)
{
    SOCKADDR_IN target = {0};
    target.sin_family = AF_INET;
    target.sin_port = htons(port);
    target.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipaddress);

    if (connect(s, (SOCKADDR*)&target, sizeof(target)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        int err = WSAGetLastError();
        switch (err)
        {
            case WSAEISCONN:
                return CTCP_DONE;

            case WSAEWOULDBLOCK:
            case WSAEALREADY:
                return CTCP_WAIT;

            default:
                sprintf(inerr, "CConnectSocket: Failed to connect the socket. Error %d", err);
                return CTCP_ERROR;
        }
    }

    return CTCP_DONE;
}
```

Comment: Just a quick question: is target = {0} the way to initialize structures to zero in c/c++?

Comment: It is one of several ways to do it. In this example, `= {0}` is explicitly initializing the first member to 0 and then value-initializing the remaining members to their default values. Can also use `= {}` instead to value-initialize the first member.

Comment: I have to disappoint us: it doesn't work. My friend is still not able to connect.

Comment: The fact that canyouseeme.org can reach your server means the problem is not on your server's end. The problem is on your friend's end. It is likely a networking problem, not a coding issue.

Comment: I got some great news! My friend manages to connect the server. Now the next problem arises: UDP. He manages to open a tcp connection with me, but then as he tries to send a packet via UDP, he fails UNLESS I specify the SOCKADDR_IN's sin_addr.s_addr without htonl() just like in the answer you gave me. The strange thing is, when I do that, it does not work at my place any more but it does do at his place. Do I have to use htonl with inet_addr or not? Is there a rule for local vs. external connections in this case?

Comment: IP addresses are handled by TCP and UDP in the *exact same manner*. DO NOT EVER use `htonl()` with `inet_addr()`. `inet_addr()` and `getaddrinfo()` ALWAYS return IPv4 addresses in network byte order, on all platforms. `sockaddr_in`/`in_addr` ALWAYS express IPv4 addresses in network byte order, on all platforms. The same `sockaddr_in` values that you use for `connect()` can also be used for `sendto()`. And likewise, the same `sockaddr_in` values that `accept()` returns are the same values that `recvfrom()` returns.

Comment: Oke, thanks for the information, then I find it very strange that by using htonl it works at my place (though I am connecting with my router's IP, so maybe some internal path returns a local IP) but not at my friends, and vice versa.

Comment: Without seeing your UDP code, there is no way for anyone here to diagnose that.